# Catalyst application still shows Fund 9

Tags: catalyst

It's Fund 10 but the catalyst application is not reflecting that. I think I may have registered again and forgotten about it. How can I confirm that my wallet id is accurate / up to date? I have my staking key, can I use that to search for my wallet Id and compare that id to what is listed in the catalyst app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fund 10 has not yet started.

The project Catalyst is on hold and it is not yet known when Fund 10 will start.

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful, where can I read more about this and why it's happening?

Comment: I think the best place is to subscribe to the project Catalyst Newsletter https://us20.campaign-archive.com/home/?u=26d3b656ecc43aa6f3063eaed&id=2451b43b07 

if this responded your question, can you please mark it so? Thank you!

Comment: Done, thank you!